# removing white background on images in flash

Tags: html, css, flash

I have removed the background of an image I am using in photoshop. Even when i export the image in flash theres no white background but everytime I add a motion tween to the image, the white background comes back so when I put it on my website you can see the white background.

Is there anyway to stop it from doing this

Comment: on the image or any of the backgrounds (besides for body) have you tried using *element{ background: transparent; }* or *element{ background-color: transparent; }*?

Comment: Try putting the image inside a `sprite` or `movieClip`, then motion tween the container itself... For quick test. Drag the image (png? gif?) onto stage, then right-click & choose to convert it to Sprite/MovieClip. Now do a test motion tween on this selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ensure the image does not include a background. Saving as a PNG often helps importing into Flash.

Then ensure the following publishing settings:

1. Choose File > Publish Settings. Make sure that HTML is selected.
2. Select HTML.
3. Choose Transparent Windowless from the Window Mode menu to make the SWF file's background disappear in browsers that support this feature.
4. Publish the document.

https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/kb/transparent-background-swf-file.html